# Shorewall "ERROR: Ordinary users may not start the /etc/shorewall configuration" in Cygwin

Tags: windows, firewall, cygwin

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 and I have installed Shorewall 4.5.21.5.
When I try to start shorewall in Cygwin, it gives me error:

```
$ shorewall start
ERROR: Ordinary users may not start the /etc/shorewall configuration
```

I tried running Cygwin using Run as Administrator but that didn't work. I have searched everywhere but haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: What happens if you try to run it using `su -c shorewall start`?